# Join two tables with switch case in order to avoid one to many join

Tags: sql, switch-statement, left-join, hiveql

I have two tables, `t1` and `t2`.

Table t1:

```
Name address id
---- ------- --
rob  32 cgr  12
mary 31 lmo  42
tom  axel St 2
```

Table t2:

```
ID Flag expense
-- ---- --------
12 Shop 1200
12 Educ 14000
42 educ 4000
```

Now I will have to create a table which will have attributes from t1 plus two more attributes that is expense in shop and expense in educ

Table t3

```
Name address id Shop_ex Educ_ex
---- ------- -- ------- -------
rob  32 cgr  12 1200    14000
mary 31 lmo  42 NULL    4000
tom  axel st 2  NULL    NULL
```

How to accomplish this?

I tried doing a left join t2 with switch case but it gives me multiple record as the join is becoming one to many.

```
select 
    t1.name, t1.address, t1.id,
    case 
        when t2.flag = "shop" then t2.expense
        else null 
    end as shop_ex
    case 
        when t2.flag = "educ" then t2.expense
        else null 
    end as educ_ex
from 
    t1 
left join 
    t2 on (t1.id = t2.id)
```

It seems I will have to convert t2 table first before joining, to have a single record on the basis of flag. But I am not sure how to do that.

Please mind the tables are huge and optimized query will be nice.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to join the first table to the second one, twice:

```sql
SELECT t1.Name, t1.address, t1.id, t2a.expense AS Shop_ex, t2b.expense AS Educ_ex
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2a
    ON t2a.ID = t1.id AND t2a.Flag = 'Shop'
LEFT JOIN table2 t2b
    ON t2b.ID = t1.id AND t2b.Flag = 'Educ'
```

### Demo